# How to redirect my website as country wise in magento2

Tags: magento2, multistore, country-regions

Hello i have multiple store for my site,like **us** and **uk** when some one from US visit my site it will **directly redirect to** ex:  **www.demo.com/us** store same for uk how to do in magento2

Comment: can you use the GeoIP Redirect for Magento 2 for amasty ?

Comment: no i didnt applied